# WPF Disable MenuItem when the other MenuItem is Checked using IValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, ivalueconverter

I tried to enable **Item2** when **Item1** is checked and disable it when **Item1** is not checked. How to do that with IValueConverter to convert IsChecked property to Boolean and bind it to IsEnabled Property in Item2.

```
<ContextMenu x:Name="ItemsContxtMenu">
<MenuItem IsCheckable="True" x:Name="Item1" Header="item1 .."/>
<MenuItem x:Name="Item2" Header="item2 .." IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=Item1, Path=IsChecked"}/>
</ContextMenu>
```

Comment: you are trying to disable MenuItem "Item2" based on it's isChecked ? but in your xaml you are trying to control based on "Item1"'s IsChecked?

Comment: @WPFUser Sorry, I edited the question.

Comment: You want to convert a bool property to bool using a converter? Why would you need that?

Comment: @RohitGarg I need a converter to invert the bool value

Answer (score 1):

You don't need converter, write following xaml:

```
<Menu VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <MenuItem Header="Items">
        <MenuItem Name="item1" Header="Item #1" IsCheckable="True" />
        <MenuItem Name="item2" Header="Item #2"  IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=item1,Path=IsChecked}" />
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Comment: But here you're using Menu. I'm using ContextMenu

Comment: Use checked and unchecked event of item1 to disable or enable of item2. this is answer of your question.